# how to have a horizontal gridview at the end of scrollview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I have a scrollview that contain details of an item in my android app, what I need is to add a horizontal list of similar items (each inflate from a layout) at the end of this view. can anybody tell me how to do this?

P.S: I've tried Recyclerview and gridview and a library form [this link](https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment) but all of them are not working inside the scrollview !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) Library. It provides horizontal gridview(one row). Just add this library dependency and put below code in bottom of your scrollView.

```
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:columnWidth="70dp"
app:rowHeight="70dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:gravity="center"/>
```